# Error when using 'BETWEEN' for retrieving a field

Tags: c#, sql, between

I'm working on a project and I'm stuck with a query. My final purpose is to get the country from an IP Address and to do that I've a database with all from-to IP addresses. My problem is that I get an error while using a query with the 'BETWEEN'. The table 'tb_CountryIP' with the informations is something like that (I've represented only the first and the last record):

```
|   ID   |   IP_From   |   IP_To    |   Country   |
|    1   |   16777216  |  16777471  |     AU      |
                      ...
| 148614 | 3758095872  | 3758096127 |     SG      |
```

My function that use the query is:

```
private string GetCountry(uint ipNum)
    {
        string resultStr= null;
        string query = $@"SELECT Country FROM tb_CountryIP WHERE '{ipNum.ToString()}' BETWEEN 'IP_From' AND 'IP_To'";

        try
        {
            using(SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStr))  // ConnectionStr reference to the connection string of the database
            {
                sqlConn.Open();

                using(SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn))
                {
                    resultStr= sqlComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            resultStr= $"Error : {ex.Message}";
        }
        return resultStr;
    }
```

And finally the error that I get is:

> Error : Riferimento a un oggetto non impostato su un'istanza di oggetto.
>   
> (Translated: Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object)

I cannot understand where the error is.

Comment: Putting the fields IP_From and IP_To between single quotes transform those names in literal strings. There is no UINT  between these two strings

Comment: So I've to remove the single quotes and than it should works? Wow, what a stupid error I did XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the fields IP_From and IP_To between single quotes transform those names in literal strings. There is no UINT between these two strings and when the code reaches the ExecuteScalar the return value is NULL. Of course trying to convert a NULL to a string raises the infamous NullReferenceException.

```
private string GetCountry(uint ipNum)
{
    string resultStr= null;
    string query = $@"SELECT Country 
                    FROM tb_CountryIP 
                    WHERE {ipNum} >= IP_From 
                      AND {ipNum} <= IP_To";

    try
    {
        using(SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStr)) 
        using(SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn))
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            object result = sqlComm.ExecuteScalar();
            if(result != null)
                resultStr = result.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        resultStr= $"Error : {ex.Message}";
    }
    return resultStr;
}
```